# Can I use a transistor to control my garage door?

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino to make a keypad to open my garage door when the correct pass code is entered. I plan on using a [MOSFET](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP30N06L.pdf) to connect the two wires that currently go to the push button in the garage. The label on the garage door opener says it's 30 volts going to the push button.  The MOSFET is rated at 60V 30A. Will this work, or do I need to use a relay?

Comment: Better give the MOSFET model number. I honestly prefer a relay because I won't need to deal with the heat sink problem.

Comment: Not sure I have enough information to answer this. Is the opener inline with the motor? I ask this because I wonder HOW much current goes through the push button. If its small(mA range), then yes the MOSFET will work fine without a heatsink. If its inline with the motor, then its likely in the amp range and will not be efficient. A heatsink will be required on the MOSFET.

Here's what I'd say. Relay would work in both cases and would be preferable. If small current, MOSFET is fine. If larger current, then it's not worth the effort of getting a viable heatsink.

Comment: Bradman, the link in my question goes to the datasheet for the MOSFET that I have

Comment: @Tolli oh silly me I didn't see that sorry.

Comment: @Tolli is your the kind where there is a big tacky up and down button that moves as long you hold them down?

Comment: My type of what? The button to open the garage? It is a simple momentary push button without a button for the light or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most door opners have terminals for a simple low-power switch to operate them.  get out your multimeter and measure the voltage on these terminals and the current when they are connected.

it's probably a DC current of 200mA or less at 24V or less,
(probably much less in both cases)

An ordinary transistor like 2n3904 would likely suffice, but your massive-overkill mosfet will do the job too, but you still need to connect it the right way round.

Comment: It is labelled 30V. I did try measuring it on the DC 10A setting on my multimeter, but it showed -0.00. I don't know if I measured it incorrectly or if it was too low to measure. I didn't want to use the lower setting because they are fused at 315mA and I didn't know if it would be higher than that.

Comment: I tested it on a lower setting. It was around 5mA

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to use a MOSFET but a lot would depend on the nature of the signalling that the goes on the wire between the opener and the wall mounted control unit. If the control unit is some type of smart unit then that may limit your options. In the end we cannot guess at all whether any particular MOSFET would work and how it would need to be wired in.

I found it much more convenient to use a low cost eBay wireless relay module and wire the NO and COM terminals of the relay directly across the push button switch contact connections. The wireless module was controlled by a carry around fob with a push button that operated at 315 MHz. You can also get low cost 315 MHz wireless transmit modules on eBay that can easily be connected to a microcontroller that mimics the protocol of the fob in software.

Comment: The signaling is just connecting the two wires (labeled P.B. and COM). It is just a simple push button that I have in my garage now and I confirmed that touching the two wires together opens the garage door. Thanks for idea of using a wireless relay. I'm not sure if it will work with my garage door opener though. It's a Wayne Dalton  Quantum and doesn't work with "universal" garage door opener remotes.

Comment: I never suggested that the relay would work with the original garage door opener. It works with a fob that comes with the wireless relay module as a set.